# why the PUT operation in nodejs throws error

Tags: node.js

POST &GET method returns expected result.,where as put&delete method returns error in browser. The flow didn't even enter put and delete method blocks in .js file.but all works fine with postman app, in chrome only POST & GET method returns result.

Comment: Could you post the code you use?

Comment: Browsers can only send GET/POST typically. You'll need some AJAX JavaScript to send PUT/DELETE

Comment: Post your sample code, are you using expressJS?

Comment: show the code you are using along with the html form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow cors for put and delete method.

set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors?rq=1)